# Web page style is garbled until clicking refresh in firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, asp-classic

I have a page that when it loads in firefox 8.0 some users report the layout is all distorted.  Clicking refresh fixes the issue.  I can't figure out how to test this since it displays just fine on my machine. No reported Javascript errors, and again, it works fine after pressing F5

[image]

## Edit:

You may view this page http://www.sc-pa.com/content/search_real_property.asp

Comment: Perhaps you recently changed the CSS and layout and they are loading the old style sheet with your new page?

Comment: FWIW it appeared fine for me first time in FF7

Comment: Hmmm...that sounds pretty good.

Comment: An image is not very helpful.  A link or code would be better, and layout is distorted in what way?

Comment: @COBOLdinosaur It seemed redundant to post the code since anyone who is interested can view the source from the link I provided.

Comment: I agree with @Manuel, this sounds like a caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, it is a caching issue, some users are using your site with an old version of your css.

Always use the version number of the website to avoid the issue in the future

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/css/site.css?v1.01"  type="text/css"  />
```